# Execute Shell Command for sending mail from PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, email, unix, plsql

We are forced to use mailx command from PL/SQL for sending mail.
Actually I have the generic script with me, but I am not sure how to execute directly in the PL/SQL code.

The code we have is

```
(echo "$mailbody" uuencode $ZIP_FILE $ZIP_FILE) | mailx -m -s "subject" -r " " "$mail_to_address"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you've explained that Oracle has built-in support through [UTL_MAIL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_mail.htm#ARPLS384) and it's foolhardy to not use the functionality your organization has already paid for :)

> " I am not sure how to execute directly in the PL/SQL code"

You can't run OS commands directly from PL/SQL. However...

Since Oracle 10g, DBMS_SCHEDULER has allowed us to call host programs. [`CREATE_PROGRAM()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72306) where `program_type => 'EXECUTABLE'`. The scheduler approach would be the best approach if you want to have a background job which polls for notifications and then sends batches of emails. Frankly the best intro the DBMS_SCHEDULER is [Tim Hall's articles on Oracle-Base](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/scheduler-10g).

But if you need on-demand execution of calls then the approach you need is a Java Stored Procedure which uses a Java `Command` object to run host calls. There can be political issues with this, because some DBAs are suspicious of Java, but it's supported. Here's [an Oracle White Paper which explains how to go about it](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/calling-shell-commands-from-plsql-1-1-129519.pdf).

Comment: thanks for your input.. but without the approval of my organization, am testing with UT_FILE, but the japanese charecters are getting corrupted and the attachment is also not going.. any way let me try this dbms_scheduler option

Comment: Actually, I had to give the necessary permissions,which are mentioned in  the oracle white paper(Which is Attached in APC's Answer) Which solved all the problems

Answer (score 1):

You can send email from a PL/SQL procedure without invoking an OS command like mailx. Some examples are here:

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Send_mail_from_PL/SQL

Example code from one of the examples:

```
DECLARE
  v_From      VARCHAR2(80) := 'oracle@mycompany.com';
  v_Recipient VARCHAR2(80) := 'test@mycompany.com';
  v_Subject   VARCHAR2(80) := 'test subject';
  v_Mail_Host VARCHAR2(30) := 'mail.mycompany.com';
  v_Mail_Conn utl_smtp.Connection;
  crlf        VARCHAR2(2)  := chr(13)||chr(10);
BEGIN
 v_Mail_Conn := utl_smtp.Open_Connection(v_Mail_Host, 25);
 utl_smtp.Helo(v_Mail_Conn, v_Mail_Host);
 utl_smtp.Mail(v_Mail_Conn, v_From);
 utl_smtp.Rcpt(v_Mail_Conn, v_Recipient);
 utl_smtp.Data(v_Mail_Conn,
   'Date: '   || to_char(sysdate, 'Dy, DD Mon YYYY hh24:mi:ss') || crlf ||
   'From: '   || v_From || crlf ||
   'Subject: '|| v_Subject || crlf ||
   'To: '     || v_Recipient || crlf ||
   crlf ||
   'some message text'|| crlf ||    -- Message body
   'more message text'|| crlf
 );
 utl_smtp.Quit(v_mail_conn);
EXCEPTION
 WHEN utl_smtp.Transient_Error OR utl_smtp.Permanent_Error then
   raise_application_error(-20000, 'Unable to send mail', TRUE);
END;
/
```